# Hibernate SaveOrUpdate with Delete

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am attempting to delete an item from a collection in a Hibernate Java object using the saveOrUpdate function on the parent object. Update and Inserts work properly, but objects are not Deleted properly. Does saveOrUpdate() have the ability to recognize and delete objects that have been removed from a parent's set?

As a side note, I have mappers that map from DB -> hibernate java object -> domain object, and the domain object is kept in session. Do I need to keep the hibernate java object in session for this to work properly?

**UPDATE (ANSWERED):** I just ended up using merge() instead of saveOrUpdate(). Merge called DELETE when necessary without having to store the java hibernate object in session.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add *delete-orphan* to the mapping. This will tell hibernate to delete 'orphaned' objects from a one to many relationship. Here's a link to the specific item in the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-transitive).

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for "delete-orphan". Check out the [reference guide on parent-child relationships](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/example-parentchild.html) and the annotations guide for [the annotation syntax](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association-cascade) for it.